# Two Means, Different Sample Size, How to Compare Using R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean

There is a sample of a student population (1,000 individuals) and from these, some were selected for an experiment (230 individuals). Now I need to compare the average of the original population to the average of those in the experiment to see if they are significantly different.

I do not have the raw data on the students or the experiment, but I do have a table with mean and SD values.

For example:

Students (SD), Experiment Population (SD)

Age 14 (.5), 15.5 (1)

Days Absent 4.2 (2), 2.7 (2.2)

Referrals 2 (.8), 3(2)

What I don't understand is that the code in R Studio for mean comparisons seems to be for the paired t-test, not for my situation. Is there alternative?

Comment: # independent 2-group t-test `t.test(y~x)`  # where y is numeric and x is a binary factor

Comment: @user158565 , except that if one group is 25% of the other group ---- that is, the one group is contained in the other ----  independent samples may not be applicable.

Comment: Cannot understand "the one group is contained in the other". Suppose you have 100 subjects, 75 of them belong to group A, also group B, and 25 just belong to group B. So group A is contained in the group B?

Answer (score 3):

Most statistics in which you test your sample parameter estimate against the population parameter assume that the values of the population are unknown. That is why a sample is taken. You test whether the sampled parameter is significantly different from zero by using a one-sample t-test.

https://www.statisticssolutions.com/manova-analysis-one-sample-t-test/

You substract from your sample mean the population mean.
As already said in real-life application the population mean is not known and usually a guess based on theory or previous research is used.

In your case, the population is known and renders the estimation through a sample obsolete. However to test whether your sample mean differs from the population mean you can just simply use the same one-sample t-test.

In R the code is

```
t.test (a, mu)
```

where a is the vector containing the sample values and mu is the population average.

@Sal commented that an issue of independence arises because you would compare a group to a subgroup of that group which would violate the assumption of independence. This would only apply to a two-sample t-test. ut because you exercise specifically states that the group is defined as the population this is not an issue and a two-sample t-test is not an appropriate test for your question

Comment: I appreciate this reply, however there seems to be one additional problem. I only have the data as it is represented in the table above, that is, I only have the mean and SD values, not the underlying observations. Can I perform an R t-test when a is simply the mean of the experimental population and mu is the mean of the student population?

Comment: @Quixotic. "Appreciating" is usually expressed by an upvote. Now, regarding your open point: You can program the formula of the one-sample t-test in R with one or two lines of code, or generate observations with exactly those means and sds of the experiment population and then use the (one-sample) `t.test` function.

Comment: @Quixotic as Michael said you can just use:

(samplemean-observedmean)/(sd(sample)*sqrt(n))